# Google sign in issue

Tags: plugins, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I use Android Studio 1.0.2

I clicked on the top right google sign in thing and I granted access on the OAuth page, but my internet suddenly dropped in between and I believe this has caused problems.

Whenever I click on the top right corner, I get the error log in IDE:

> IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null

I tried to click on sign out, but nothing happens (I keep getting this log). I restarted android studio and it still shows me as logged in, but I get the same error when I try to sign out or even click on the top right picture.

My question is: How do I reset only this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Please login to your google account and go to
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Here you will see the name of your application with which you attempted google sign in. Click on the application and click "Revoke Access" on the right panel.

You can run your app again. You should not receive any error now.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled "google login" plugin in android studio and then enabled it. This fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, remember that uninstalling an application does not remove the previous configuration files used by Android Studio and X-Window.

So before launching your updated AS, remove the following directories:

```
~/.AndroidStudio*
~/.java/.userPrefs
```