# Android Studio exception in plugin Google Login "'userEmail' of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-signin

Using Android Studio 1.2.1.1.  When clicking the login icon (top right) I get this exception.

```
Argument for @NotNull parameter 'userEmail' of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'userEmail' of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null
    at com.google.gct.login.CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser(CredentialedUserRoster.java)
    at com.google.gct.login.GoogleLogin.setActiveUser(GoogleLogin.java:454)
    at com.google.gct.login.ui.GoogleLoginUsersPanel.valueChanged(GoogleLoginUsersPanel.java:232)
    at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)
    at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:154)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:685)
    at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(JList.java:2142)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicListUI.java:2796)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have tried to fix it by doing the following (no success):

- rebooting my computer.
- reinstalling Android Studio
- following the suggested solution in   [Google sign in issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813147/google-sign-in-issue).  I have revoked access to everything related to Android, Android Studio and the SDKs.
- disabling and re-enabling the "Google Login" plugin

How can this be fixed?  Or where should I look for this missing 'userEmail' parameter?

The same problem manifest in a different exception when I try to deploy my module to app engine:

```
Exception loading projects for null: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been revoked."
}
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been revoked."
}
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:247)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.google.gct.idea.elysium.GoogleUserModelItem.loadUserProjects(GoogleUserModelItem.java:130)
at com.google.gct.idea.elysium.GoogleUserModelItem.access$100(GoogleUserModelItem.java:41)
at com.google.gct.idea.elysium.GoogleUserModelItem$1.run(GoogleUserModelItem.java:95)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Note that this problem is not solved by the suggested solution in   [Google sign in issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813147/google-sign-in-issue).  That solution suggests going to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 and revoking application access.  I have allowed no access related to Android, Android Studio and the SDKs.  Other applications running on my PC, like Chrome, can log in without issue.

Comment: Hi , Did you solved this issue? I am also in the same trouble..Please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was a bug in Android Studio.  It disappeared when I upgraded to the latest "canary channel" version.  See http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12beta3available to see what was fixed.  FYI the version that works for me is:

```
Android Studio AI-141.1962279
Build #AI-141.1962279, built on May 27, 2015
JRE: 1.7.0_79-b15 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```