# Android Studio does not deploy Google Cloud Module

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have a Android Studio Google Cloud Module application as a backend for my Android project. When I try to deploy this module on Google Cloud, I have the following error:

`Argument for @NotNull parameter 'userEmail' of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null.`

The local server works fine.

I have tried uninstalling/installing both the Android SDK and Android Studio completely, and failed to correct the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google sign in issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813147/google-sign-in-issue)

Comment: I've tried everything in the given answer but it still didn't washed away. The problem had disappeared after an upgrade, but now it's back.

Comment: I am using AS 2.0 Preview 4 and the problem still persists.