# Error/unable to logging in Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, google-apps, google-plugin-eclipse

When I attempt to Sign in in Google Plugin in Android Studio for login services it is throwing the error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'userEmail' of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null
```

I have tried the following steps:

1. Restarting Android Studio
2. Restarting my Mac machine.
3. Disabling and enabling plugin for Google Login
4. Clearing cache and preferences along with logs of Android Studio in ~/Library/

I have been trying to fix this from last two days now. None of the above worked. I am using Android Studio v1.3.2 latest build on 19 August.

Comment: Where is your code ?? Are we supposed to use a crystal ball ?

Comment: @2Dee What has it to do with code? Did you read my question properly!

Comment: Yes he did. The error is telling you that you are passing `null` for the `userEmail` parameter when calling `setActiveUser()`. If you don't believe this is the case, showing the code where you are calling this method should shed some light on the matter.

Comment: FYI, I create a fresh project in my android studio. Tap on the top right corner to Sign in or Add Account and the error comes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is not related to code. I had the same problem and that log is shown by Google Login plugin.

My recommendation is to uninstall and install the last [version](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12beta3available).

Other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813147/google-sign-in-issue).